# Not able to show negative signs

Tags: math-operators

I have the following.

```
\item Arrange in ascending order (smallest to largest): $−6, −2, 0, 1, −5, 4, 3$
```

But this output does not have negative signs.

```
6, 2, 0, 1, 5, 4, 3
```

It shows negative in other places.

```
\item Evaluate $(-2)^2$
```

This output has a negative sign.

Evaluate (−2)<sup>2</sup>

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The minus signs in `$−6, −2, 0, 1, −5, 4, 3$` are not hyphens `-` (0x2d) but dashes `−` (0x2212). A dash is slightly longer than a hyphen.

**Solution:** Replace dashes with hyphens.

The minus sign in `\item Evaluate $(-2)^2$` is already a hyphen.

Comment: Note that `\usepackage{lmodern}` is extremely illuminating in this respect!

Comment: Thanks. It happened so because I copy and paste it from MS Word.

Comment: @shin That warning is good to know, re: MS Word.

Comment: The advice is correct but note that U+2212 isn't a "dash" it is "MINUS SIGN" so typographically it's the correct character, so in unicode-math it should work, but for classic tex, as you say you should use `-` just as you should use `\`` and `'` rather than typographical left and right qutes as TeX input.

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing much copy-paste from word processors, then it's better to load

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

in your LaTeX document. Then you can teach LaTeX new correspondences between Unicode characters and LaTeX set of known objects, in this case

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

%% the first is the “unknown minus” (U+2212), the second is a hyphen
\newunicodechar{−}{-}

\begin{document}
$−1$
\end{document}
```

How do you know there's something amiss? Look in the .log file: you should find several instances of something like

```
Missing character: There is no <E2> in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no <88> in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no <92> in font cmr10!
```

one for each “disappearing” minus sign. Indeed, if you don't load `inputenc` with the `utf8` option, TeX just sees the three byte representation of U+2212, precisely the bytes `0xE2`, `0x88` and `0x92` that don't correspond to a printable character, because the default TeX fonts have only 128 glyphs.

With `utf8`, but no `\newunicodechar` declaration you'd get an error:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:− not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

and you can so understand what went wrong: the minus sign is not understood. Copy it and use it for defining the correct `\newunicodechar` declaration.